# How to fetch the schema from schema registry using subject and version using java

Tags: java, api

Needed a java code to fetch the schema from the schema registry using the subject and version.

Comment: Which schema registry?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tgdavies avro schema

Comment: Have a look at https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html